# What is the sum of all the numbers on the opposite faces of numbers obtained in three rows is?

Tags: dice

I have this:
A person threw a standard dice three times. He obtained two distinct odd prime numbers in two throws and an even number which is not a factor of 18 in the third throw. The sum of all the numbers on the opposite faces of numbers obtained in the three rows is?
( Answer : 9 )

In this,
It is given,
He obtained two distinct odd prime numbers in two throws 
Distinct odd prime numbers in a dice are 3 i.e., 1,3 and 5

And
an even number which is not a factor of 18 in the third throw
So the number will be 4.

But how do I find the sum of all numbers on the opposite faces of numbers in three rows?
A supportive explaination would do great:)

Comment: Trivia fun fact:  The opposite sides of a die add to seven.  $1$ is opposite $6$, $2$ is opposite $5$ and $3$ is opposite $4$.  There's no math... just ... trivia.

Comment: So if the three rolls are $a + b + c$ then the opposite sides will be $(7-a) + (7-b) + (7-c) = 21 - (a+b+c)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of a face with its opposite face is always $7$. So we have that the opposite faces of $3$, $5$ and $4$ are $4$, $2$ and $3$ respectively. From there we have the answer: $4+2+3=9$.

Comment: So yes, I made a mistake considering 1 as a prime number and thus was unable to figure that out. And I forgot the fact that 1 is neither prime nor composite =_= Anyways, thanks!